# How eval() value on select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form

```js
var number = $('.price').text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
$('input#pricea').attr('value', number)
$("select.percent").change(function() {
  var selectedPercent = $(this).children("option:selected").val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  $('input#percenta').attr('value', selectedPercent)
});

var x = eval("number* selectedPercent") + "<br>";
$('#demo').attr('value', x)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">300 $</div>
<select class="percent">
  <option value="0">0%</option>
  <option value="30%">30%</option>
  <option value="40%">40%</option>
  <option value="50%">50%</option>
  <option value="60%">60%</option>
</select>
<div id="demo"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="pricea" id="pricea">
<input type="hidden" name="percenta" id="percenta" value="0">
```

Finally `#demo` don't show `value` . Can someone help me? pls. And Because I used the `select` , I want to select the options that will return different results at `#demo`

Comment: Don't ever use `eval()`. It's not meant to be used in modern scripts (it's from a much older version of JS, and only still exists because JS never _removes_ features. They just become things you should never do. Like using `document.write` or `alert()`. And it should go without saying, but don't use those either, of course)

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use `eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) for this. Instead, *inside* your `.change()` callback convert your string number into an actual number (which is done for you when you use `*`) and then display the output using `.append()` (this will allow multiple numbers to be shown each change, use `.html()` or `.text()` to show one number per change). Also, to get the selected value you can simply do `$(this).val()` and remove the `%` from each `<option>` value attribute (so you don't need to remove it using regex), there is no need to get the selected child option.

```js
var number = $('.price').text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
$('input#pricea').attr('value', number)
$("select.percent").change(function() {
  var selectedPercent = $(this).val();
  $('input#percenta').attr('value', selectedPercent);
  
  var x = (number * selectedPercent) + "<br>";
  $('#demo').append(x);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price">300 $</div>
<select class="percent">
  <option value="0">0%</option>
  <option value="30">30%</option>
  <option value="40">40%</option>
  <option value="50">50%</option>
  <option value="60">60%</option>
</select>
<div id="demo"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="pricea" id="pricea">
<input type="hidden" name="percenta" id="percenta" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use append('yourdata') or html('yourdata') to show data into div. try following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var number =$('.price').text().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
$('input#pricea').attr('value',number);
var selectedPercent = $("select.percent").children("option:selected").val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');        
var x = eval("number* selectedPercent") + "<br>";
$('#demo').html(x);

$("select.percent").change(function(){
        selectedPercent = $(this).children("option:selected").val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        $('input#percenta').attr('value',selectedPercent)
        var y = eval("number* selectedPercent") + "<br>";
        $('#demo').html(y);

    });
});
```